# the parameter of RNN in Theano tutorial

Tags: theano, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

```
class RNNSLU(object):
''' elman neural net model '''
def __init__(self, nh, nc, ne, de, cs):
    '''
    nh :: dimension of the hidden layer
    nc :: number of classes
    ne :: number of word embeddings in the vocabulary
    de :: dimension of the word embeddings
    cs :: word window context size
    '''
    # parameters of the model
    self.emb = theano.shared(name='embeddings',
                             value=0.2 * numpy.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0,
                             (ne+1, de))
                             # add one for padding at the end
                             .astype(theano.config.floatX))
    self.wx = theano.shared(name='wx',
                            value=0.2 * numpy.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0,
                            (de * cs, nh))
                            .astype(theano.config.floatX))
    self.wh = theano.shared(name='wh',
                            value=0.2 * numpy.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0,
                            (nh, nh))
                            .astype(theano.config.floatX))
    self.w = theano.shared(name='w',
                           value=0.2 * numpy.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0,
                           (nh, nc))
                           .astype(theano.config.floatX))
    self.bh = theano.shared(name='bh',
                            value=numpy.zeros(nh,
                            dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    self.b = theano.shared(name='b',
                           value=numpy.zeros(nc,
                           dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    self.h0 = theano.shared(name='h0',
                            value=numpy.zeros(nh,
                            dtype=theano.config.floatX))

    # bundle
    self.params = [self.emb, self.wx, self.wh, self.w, self.bh, self.b, self.h0]



def recurrence(x_t, h_tm1):
        h_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, self.wx)
                             + T.dot(h_tm1, self.wh) + self.bh)
        s_t = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(h_t, self.w) + self.b)
        return [h_t, s_t]

[h, s], = theano.scan(fn=recurrence,
                            sequences=x,
                            outputs_info=[self.h0, None],
                            n_steps=x.shape[0])
```

I am following this Theano tutorial about RNN.(http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rnnslu.html) But I have two questions about it.
First. In this tutorial, recurrence function like this:

`def recurrence(x_t, h_tm1):
            h_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, self.wx) + T.dot(h_tm1, self.wh)  + self.bh)
            s_t = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(h_t, self.w) + self.b)
            return [h_t, s_t]`

I wounder why do not plus h0 in h_t ? (i.e. `h_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, self.wx) + T.dot(h_tm1, self.wh)  + self.bh  + self.h0)`)

Second, why `outputs_info=[self.h0, None]`? I know outputs_info is the Initialization result. So I think `outputs_info=[self.bh+self.h0, T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(self.bh+self.h0, self.w_h2y) + self.b_h2y)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def recurrence(x_t, h_tm1):
        h_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, self.wx)
                             + T.dot(h_tm1, self.wh) + self.bh)
        s_t = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(h_t, self.w) + self.b)
        return [h_t, s_t]
```

So, first you ask why we don't use h0 in the recurrence function. Let's breakdown this part,

```
   h_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, self.wx)+ T.dot(h_tm1, self.wh) + self.bh)
```

What we expect is 3 terms.

1. The first term is the input layer multiplied by the weighting matrix `T.dot(x_t, self.wx)`.
2. The second term is the hidden layer muliplied by another weighting matrix (this is what makes it recurrent) `T.dot(h_tm1, self.wh)`. Note that you must have a weighting matrix, you proposed to add `self.h0` as a bias basically.
3. The third term is the bias of the hidden layer, `self.bh`.

Now, after every iteration we want to keep track of the hidden layer activations, contained in `self.h0`. However, `self.h0` is meant to contain the CURRENT activations and what we need is the previous activations.

```
[h, s], _ = theano.scan(fn=recurrence,
                            sequences=x,
                            outputs_info=[self.h0, None],
                            n_steps=x.shape[0])
```

So, look at the scan function again. You are right that `outputs_info=[self.h0, None]` initializes the values, but the values are also linked to the outputs. There are two outputs from `recurrence()`, namely `[h_t, s_t]`.

So what the outputs_info does as well is that after every iteration, the value of `self.h0` is overwritten with the value of `h_t` (the first returned value). The second element of outputs_info is `None`, because we do not save or initialize the value for `s_t` anywhere (the second argument of outputs_info is linked to the returned values of the recurrence function this way.)

In the next iteration, the first argument of `outputs_info` is used again as input, such that `h_tm1` is the same value as `self.h0`. But, since we must have an argument for `h_tm` we must initialize this value. Since we don't need to initialize a second argument in `outputs_info`, we leave the second term as `None`.

Granted, the `theano.scan()` function is very confusing at times and I'm new at it too. But, this is what I understood from doing this same tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's so useful, I think that I understand what you mean, thank you so much